# Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E4300 - Is it a 64 Bit Processor?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I have a PC with an Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E4300 - I ran CPU-ID on it, and here are the results:

[image]

Is this capable of running Windows 64-bit?

Comment: If your CPU is not an E4300, google/bing the manufactures specifications for your processor model and look for tabular data listing specifications; 64 bit architecture is generally high up in the data list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, all Core 2 Duo chips are 64-bit capable, that is includes the EM64T feature. Of course, if your running a 32-bit OS then it'll be no different then a 32-bit chip, but if you
put a 64-bit OS on your system the Core 2 Duo chips will handle
it properly. So yes it is capable of running 64-bit Windows.

however please note;

> Intel® EM64T requires a computer
>   system with a processor, chipset,
>   BIOS, operating system, device drivers
>   and applications enabled for Intel
>   EM64T. Processor will not operate
>   (including 32-bit operation) without
>   an Intel EM64T-enabled BIOS.
>   Performance will vary depending on
>   your hardware and software
>   configurations.

http://processorfinder.intel.com/details.aspx?sSpec=SL9TB

Answer (score 1):

According to [Intel](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=28024), yes, it is a 64 bit processor.

Answer (score 0):

All Intel Core-2 processors contain the 64 bit instuction sets.